# Why can't i add Bin Folder in an asp.net MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a web application using asp.net MVC...

```
RightClick->Add->Add ASP.Net folder-> there is no bin folder...
```

I am using `asp.net MVC 1.0` with `visual studio 2008 sp1`... Any suggestion...

I find a **bin folder** in my root folder,but not in the solution explorer..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Solution Explorer Click **Show All Files** Icon


[image]

Then Click Right on Bin then  select Include In Project


[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the top of the solution explorer and find the button that says "Show all files" or something to that effect, you should be able to find the bin folder that way. Then just right click and select "Include in Project".